# Category and post tag archives do not include posts from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

My custom post type is configured to use `category` and `post_tag` taxonomies. The categories and tags display fine in the admin and appear to function as expected. The categories also display fine in the UI, however when I click on a category name in the UI, the category template displays, but the WordPress loop contains no posts even though I can verify that multiple posts are associated with that category.

Perhaps my custom post type needs to be configured differently?

```
function create_newz() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'                => 'The Newz',
    'singular_name'       => 'Newz Item',
    'menu_name'           => 'Newz',
    'name_admin_bar'      => 'Newz',
    'add_new'             => 'Add Newz Item',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add Newz',
    'new_item'            => 'New Newz Item',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Newz Item',
    'view_item'           => 'View Newz Item',
    'all_items'           => 'All Newz Items',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Newz',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Newz:',
    'not_found'           => 'No Newz Items found.',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'No Newz Items found in Trash.'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'public'              => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-id-alt',
    'query_var'           => true,
    'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'newz'),
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'hierachical'         => false,
    'supports'            => array('title','editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
  );
  register_post_type('newz', $args);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WordPress will only include the `post` post type within the `post_tag` and `category` taxonomy archives.

Use this snippet to add `newz` posts to the `post_tag` and `category` taxonomy archives:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_newz_taxonomy_archives' );
function wpse_newz_taxonomy_archives( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( is_category() || is_tag() ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'newz' ) );
  }
}
```